# Creating an Executable Script which accesses aspx form components and runs function

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello I have created and application which contains a gridview that is populated by an SQL database. I built a function which converts the gridview into an excel file and stores it on the server.

I would just like to know how I can write an executable script(which I will set to run at a certain time on the server) that will access the gridview in the .aspx file containing the gridview and run the convertToExcel() function located in the .cs file attached to the .aspx file and then close.

Thank you,
Fernando Diaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me, I'd separate out the code that performs the data retrieval for the gridview and the Excel processing into it's own class library project.  Then, with that DLL, createa  console application that calls those functions.  You can schedule a windows service to execute that .exe daily.

With that said.

To specifically answer your question.  You need to create a console application and request the page using an HttpWebRequest

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    // prepare the web page you are asking for
    HttpWebRequest  request  = (HttpWebRequest)
        WebRequest.Create("http://www.yourpage.com");

    // execute the request
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
        request.GetResponse();
    }
```

Because it seems you don't need to read the response, this should be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, TheGeekYouNeed.
But how would I run the function inside the .cs attached to the aspx file.
I am pretty new to asp.net.

Comment: You "Add Reference" to the DLL you make in your console application.

Then, whatever you name it, you would place a using statement at the top of y ou .cs file for it:

such as 

    using MyUtilityLibrary;


Then in code, depending how you define your method, you call it.  Let's assume you make a static method called GenerateExcelReport (in the DLL)

    MyUtilityLibrary.GenerateExcelReport();